# Unable to delete object using datastore, query (with `id`) on dao and ds return zero result

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, mongodb-java

I'm trying to delete an object from datastore but it's not deleting it. Code is given below:

```
MoIADocument moIADoc = new MoIADocument();
// update fields in moIADoc object
ds.save(moIADoc);

printDBDocs();

// create a query to retrieve objects
QueryResults<MoIADocument> foundResults = dao.find(query);
List<MoIADocument> list = foundResults.asList();

for (MoIADocument obj : list) {
    ds.delete(obj);
    MoDBIATopic topicBO = obj.getData().get(EnumChannelType.FACEBOOK).getData().get(GraphConstants.Topic_Default);
    topicBO.setInfluence(topicBO.getInfluence() * 25);
    ds.save(obj);
}
printDBDocs();
```

`###########################`
the result of first print (in JSON format) is:

[image: first print result]

`###########################`
obj in `for` loop is:

[image: obj in for loop]

`###########################`
and after for loop the print statement gives two objects as:

[image: last print result]

Why is it not deleting old object by `mongoConstants.ds.delete(obj);`? And I have annotated `id` field ad `@Id` but still two objects are saved with same `id`. How is this possible? How can we force to overwrite an object if `id` is same?

```
@Id
@Indexed
private String id;
```

Note: `id` is the top level `id` as indicated in JSON.

And I tried using query as:

```
Query<MoIADocument> query1 = ds.createQuery(MoIADocument.class).disableValidation();
query1.field("id").equal(obj.getId());
ds.delete(query1);
```

This too not working as expected.

`EDIT:`

Problem looks like in query result. Using above `query1`, it returned zero results.

Comment: Why are you deleting a document, updating one field and then saving it again? Why not use just update operation?

Comment: because I want to update it's field using an expression like, value=value/someValue, which is not possible using update.

Comment: well, you can read just the necessary field and then use its value to do the update

Comment: but that would be much complex (to create UpdateOperations) if many fields are changed.. So I felt better to delete old and save new one..

Comment: isn't there any way to keep any field (say `id`) as unique, may be using some annotation? (I think `@Id` keeps it unique, but don't know how two object with same `id` got created?) (ref: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/EntityAnnotation#@Id )

Comment: how many fields will change? Delete and save isn't a good pratice

Comment: Different number of changes for different cases. almost all numeric fields get modified in worst case.

Comment: what does `ds.merge(T arg0)` do? though using this gave me an error:  `Exception in thread "main" com.google.code.morphia.query.UpdateException: Not updated: { "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "updatedExisting" : false , "n" : 0 , "connectionId" : 178 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
 at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.merge(DatastoreImpl.java:890)`

Comment: Have you tried query documents, modify then (java code) and use Dao.save? It should update the role objet (http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/DAOSupport)

Comment: Are you using DAO support or not?

Comment: yes I'm using it.. That too gave same results as using `ds`.

Comment: So, does read and save (without deleting) using DAO works for you?

Comment: sorry.. no, it's not working too.. I had mistake in query formation (used `query` instead of `query1`, see in question).. After modification, I can see no deletion of object is happening.

Comment: so, is it working now?

Comment: no I found the problem is in querying only.. I used query with id (which in JSON format was like `{ "id" : "51d56f11b760dbacd2b3159b"}`) to retrieve result, but it returned zero documents.. Now it's (mongodb / morphia) looking like deep dark black box :P

Comment: Perhaps the correct query is: `{ "_id" : "51d56f11b760dbacd2b3159b"}`. With underscore on id field

Comment: nope... I used `id` as field with `@Id` in my class.. (using `_id` do not work too, which is expected)

Comment: finally found the problem.. posting the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was using a `String id` as `@Id` field. Actually it should be `ObjectId id`. WIth this change class become as below:

```
@Entity("Collection_IAGlobals")
public class MoDBIADocument {
    @Id
    @Indexed
    private ObjectId id;
    // some more fields
}
```

and updating as:

```
QueryResults<MoIADocument> foundResults = dao.find(query);
List<MoIADocument> list = foundResults.asList();
for (MoIADocument obj : list) {
    //do modifications in obj
    dao.save(obj);
}
```

this way there is no need to `delete` old object. It replaces old object with new one (since they are having same `id`).

Works fine using both `ds` and `dao`.

But now, new problem with setting `id` field. If I set using some string as:

```
moIADoc.setId(new ObjectId("123456"));
```

it is resulting into following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid ObjectId [123456]
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:128)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:122)
```

It works fine any of other methods, like:

```
// don't set id field
//OR
//set using default constructor of ObjectId
moIADoc.setId(new ObjectId());
//OR use other constructors e.g.
moIADoc.setId(new ObjectId(new Date(), 123456));
```

So, the question is why `ObjectId` is not taking `String` argument?

Comment: You've answered your original question, but posted a second question in the answer - you should really put this as a new question.  However, to answer it, your String is not a valid object ID, it's not allowed to be an arbitrary String, it has to be a valid ID, e.g. "51d5909a30042ec0967e66ff"

Comment: So does it mean we cannot have our own unique keys? If I have unique key for each object, how can I use them as id?

Comment: You can use your own unique ID, but I don't think you can once you've got an _id field in your collection in the database.

Comment: It'll not create `_id` field before saving. And even if I set `id` using `moIADoc.setId(new ObjectId("123456"));` before `moIADoc` being saved **first time**, it's resulting into above Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple approaches but nothing worked as expected.. tried following ways:

Approach# 1:

```
Query<MoDBIADocument> query1 = dao.createQuery(MoDBIADocument.class).disableValidation();
query1.field("id").equal(moDoc.getId());
QueryResults<MoDBIADocument> foundResults1 = dao.find(query1);
printDBDocs(foundResults1);
```

Approach# 2: (using `_id` instead of `id`)

```
Query<MoDBIADocument> query1 = dao.createQuery(MoDBIADocument.class).disableValidation();
query1.field("_id").equal(moDoc.getId());
QueryResults<MoDBIADocument> foundResults1 = dao.find(query1);
printDBDocs(foundResults1);
```

Approach# 3:

```
using `ds` instead of `dao` in `Approach# 1` and `Approach# 2`
```

Approach# 4:

```
DBObject dbObj = new BasicDBObject("id", moDoc.getId());
DBCursor cursor = COLLECTION.find(dbObj);
```

None of above approaches worked.. I think problem is with using top level `id` field (somehow?)..

Using internal id (of `FACEBOOK`) worked as expected

```
query1.field("data.FACEBOOK.id").equal(str);
```